# rhq default user/password - whe

Tags: authentication, passwords, rhq

I just installed latest rhq rhq-server-4.10.0,

I go into

```
http://myrhq:7080/coregui/
```

and try to login with admin and with  rhqadmin and password used for database, but it doesn't work (actually not strange cause I tried with database password - not application which I don't know).

Where is user / password for

```
http://myrhq:7080/coregui/ defined ?
```

How can I login into application ?

BR,

Jakub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default username/password after install are rhqadmin/rhqadmin as described in the ["Running the server"](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Running+the+RHQ+Server#RunningtheRHQServer-Logginginandfirststeps) docs.

You can then go in the UI to Administration->Users and change the password:

[image: screenshot of RHQ user admin ui]

This is also the place to set up more users and assign them roles etc.
The later is described in the [rhq wiki](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Security+Model).